# Acceptance Test with Identity Server and Specflow .Net

Tags: identityserver4, specflow, acceptance-testing

I Need to test with specflow an api endpoint that has been protected with identinty server but I don't know how to do that, I've created an a WebApplication in my specflow project but when the test post a request, the response return status 500 because the API can't access .well-known/openid-configuration.

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro], and include more information about the protocols used for the identity server.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the Auth server is not accessible during the unit test run. The API endpoint needs to validate the token against the Auth server.

What you need to do is have an auth server running separately before the unit tests (integration tests) are run.

I suspect you are attempting to run an instance of your AuthServer using something like WebApplicationFactory. This won't work because the service isn't available for the follow up call to the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint.